# Can you group like rows in one column, but keep other columns separated?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to filter through my data, but come across similar row values under Column1. Column2 and Column3 values are different per row.

```
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3
|---------|---------|--------
|    a    |    1    |    6
|    b    |    2    |    7
|    a    |    3    |    8
|    c    |    4    |    9
|    b    |    5    |    10
```

Is there a way to group Column1 values but keep Column2 and 3 separated? Column1 order does not matter.

```
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3
|---------|---------|--------
|    a    |    1    |    6
|         |    3    |    8
|    c    |    4    |    9
|    b    |    2    |    7
|         |    5    |    10
```

Comment: Are you talking about *displaying* these tables, or their actual *content*?

Comment: I believe content. The data will eventually export to an excel document, where the desired table format is required. Would it be easier to export the raw data, then reformat through VBA?

Comment: This is usually done in your own application view.

Comment: If you "erase" elements in Column1, how will you know what values they used to have in order to organize the rows properly?

Comment: Next time.. do submit a SQL Fiddle link which helps

Answer (score 0):

This script works on mysql 8

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t (col1 char(1), col2 int, col3 int);
insert into t values ('a',1,6);
insert into t values ('b',2,7);
insert into t values ('a',3,8);
insert into t values ('c',4,9);
insert into t values ('b',5,10);

select 
    case when col1_1 > 1 then '' else col1 end as col1
    ,col2
    ,col3
from
(
select 
    col1
    ,row_number() Over(partition by col1 order by col1) col1_1
    ,col2
    ,col3
from t
) x
```

Comment: Did this work for you Austin ? Closing the question will help others too.